# ¿como validar el zoom del navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

una pregunta, como validar que al recargar el zoom del navegador siempre este al 100%? 
[image: ver el 90%]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es asegurarte que al recargar la página vas a tener un zoom del 100%, podrías utilizar la propiedad **[`transform: scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)** de CSS, con la cual puedes fijar la escala que va a tener tu página (una escala de 1 significará que va a tener un zoom del 100%, una escala de 2, un 200%, y así sucesivamente).

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo con una escala de 3 (300%):

```css
body{
   transform: scale(3);
   transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="conZoom">Esto es una prueba</p>
<p id="sinZoom">Esto es una prueba</p>
<img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_800_800/AAEAAQAAAAAAAARpAAAAJDMzZGRhNGMwLTU4YmMtNDdmZi1hMjU5LWIwYTViMjdlNWJmOQ.png">
```

En tu caso simplemente tendrías que indicar que quieres una escala de 1 para obtener el 100% de zoom.

**¿Por qué utilizo la propiedad `transform: scale` en vez de la propiedad `zoom` de CSS?**

Porque la propiedad `transform: scale` soporta todos los navegadores más conocidos, incluido Internet Explorer 11. Puedes ver las compatibilidades con está propiedad **[aquí](https://caniuse.com/#search=scale())**.

Sin embargo, la propiedad `zoom` no soporta Firefox (sin utilizar prefijos). Puedes verlo **[aquí](https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom)**.

En caso de que quisieras soportar versiones de Internet Explorer inferiores a la 9, podrías utilizar la propiedad `zoom` en su defecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, me sirvio :)

Comment: Listo, de nuevo mil gracias. !!!

Comment: @Francisco no termino de entender. Veo que la propiedad escala a cada objeto, pero ¿esto está relacionado al zoom del navegador seleccionado por el usuario? Si cambio el zoom del navegador, tu ejemplo se carga en un tamaño diferente